# Reflection with winmd file

Tags: c#, reflection, winmd

I want to use the reflection process in my c# app with

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load()
```

My problem is I don't want to use it with a .DLL file but with a .winmd file (in my case Windows.winmd).

Is it possible ?

Comment: Wihdows.winmd does not contain any code.  It is just metadata for the compiler, it declares the WinRT types.  They are implemented by the OS.  So it isn't very obvious why reflection would be useful or necessary.  If you are doing this to avoid using an api that is not available on an earlier version of UWP then you are supposed to [do this](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/).